# XSLT setting a variable to either foo or @foo depending on presence of attribute

Tags: xslt

I'm trying to set parttext to @head if `use_head="true"` is not present and to the contents of `<head>` `</head>` if `use_head="true"` is present

```
<xsl:template match="toc_part">

    <xsl:variable name="artnum">
        <xsl:value-of select="../@num" />
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="partnum">
        <xsl:value-of select="@num" />
    </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:variable name="parttext">
            <xsl:if test="@use_head">
                <xsl:value-of select="head"/>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="not[@use_head]">
                <xsl:value-of select="@head"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:variable> 


    <tr>
        <td>
             
        </td>
        <td>
            <a class="int" href="{$GBLfilePre}{$artnum}.html#{$artnum}{$partnum}"><xsl:text>Part </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$partnum" /></a>

        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="$parttext" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

I've also tried:

```
<xsl:if test="@use_head"><xsl:variable name="parttext"><xsl:value-of select="head"></xsl:variable>
<xsl:if test="not[@use_head"]><xsl:variable name="parttext"><xsl:value-of select="@head"></xsl:variable>
```

which give parttext undefined when referenced.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<xsl:variable name="parttext">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@use_head='true'">
            <xsl:value-of select="head"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="@head"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current test in the first if statement will evaluate to `true()` if the `@use_head` attribute exists, regardless of it's value. If you want the test to evaluate whether or not it's value is equal to "true" you should use `test="@use_head='true'"`.

The second if statement is evaluating whether or not there is an element named "not" that has an attribute called "use_head", because the square brackets are a predicate. I believe you had intended to use the `not()` function: `not(@use_head='true')`

You could then use an `<xsl:choose>` instead of two if blocks:

```
<xsl:variable name="parttext">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="@use_head='true'">
      <xsl:value-of select="head"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="@head"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 2.0:

```
<xsl:variable name="head" 
     select="if (@use_head='true') then head else @head"/>
```

In XSLT 1.0, either Hansen's solution, or

```
<xsl:variable name="head" 
     select="head[current()/@use_head='true'] |
             @head[not(current()/@use_head='true')]"/>
```

In future, please tell us which version of XSLT you are using. One can sort of guess this must be XSLT 1.0 because in 2.0 the solution is trivial, but it's better not to have to guess.